# firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged() function is called multiple times even after unsubscribing

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

```js
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```
var unSubscribe=firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.

  window.location.replace("library.html");
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    if(user != null){

      var email_id = user.email;
      //document.getElementById("user_para").innerHTML = "Welcome User : " + email_id;

    }

  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
    window.location.replace("index.html");
  }
  unSubscribe();
});

function login(){

  var userEmail = document.getElementById("email_field").value;
  var userPass = document.getElementById("password_field").value;

  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPass).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;

    window.alert("Error : " + errorMessage);

    // ...
  });

}

function logout(){
  firebase.auth().signOut();
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Firebase Login</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

</head>

<body>

  <div id="login_div" class="main-div">
    <h3>Firebase Web login Example</h3>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email..." id="email_field" />
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password..." id="password_field" />

    <button onclick="login()">Login to Account</button>
  </div>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.8.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.8.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.8.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
  <script>
    // Initialize Firebase
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: ,
    authDomain: ,
    databaseURL: ,
    projectId: ,
    storageBucket: ,
    messagingSenderId:,
    appId: ,
    measurementId: 
  };
    // Initialize Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  </script>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

(library.html also has the same script tags.) 
I have seen similar questions and the answers to them were to call the function returned by firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(), so I implemented that but the index.html page keeps reloading multiple times. I have implemented the functionality for a single html page by hiding and displaying elements and it worked fine before.
I have also tried inserting the window.location.replace() in the login and logout functions but that on browser gives a blank html page and no errors on inspect.
Please help me with the issue, I am a beginner at javascript and web development.

Comment: The issue was solved by using window.location.href ="hostel.html"; inside the if(user!=null) condition in the index.js file and maintaining two different .js files each for index and library.

Answer (score 0):

You say both HTML pages have the same script running. So when you redirect to either page, the code will run again, trying to redirect you again.

If this is indeed the problem, a quick fix might be to pass a query param like `redirect=true`, and then only execute the code when this param is false.

`window.location.replace("library.html?redirect=true");`

then parse your url with a regex f.e.

```
const wasRedirected = new Regex(/[?&]redirect=(true|false)/g).exec(window.location)[1] === 'true'
```

Comment: That might be the case! Could you please tell me how to pass query param redirect, sorry I am new at webdevelopment so if you could please tell me about it

Comment: Its still behaving the same way, no improvements! "http://localhost/RoliLogin/firebaseWebLogin/index.html?redirect=true " keeps loading multiple times

Answer (score 0):

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged() function sets an observer on the Auth Object. And as an observer, it continuously checks for the state of the authorization. That's why the index.html page keeps on reloading. The solution is to call the onAuthStateChanged() function only one time when your window reloads for the first time. Add the following code in the index.js file.

```
window.onload = unSubscribe;
```

Hope it helps.